# Getting error while setting up AudienceManager

Tags: audience-manager

Extended detail 'E-mail address' is not mandatory, while it is marked as (part of) the contact's identification. Please make sure all extended details that are marked as identification key are mandatory.

```
StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.ExtendedDetailsDal.ValidateIdentificationKeys(Dictionary`2 details, Dictionary`2 uniqueIndexInfo)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.ExtendedDetailsDal.ExtendedDetails()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.ExtendedDetailCollection..ctor(UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.OutboundEmailServiceBase`1.CreateUserContext()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.OutboundEmailServiceBase`1.ThreadLoop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When is this error happening?

You may want to verify that in the Audience Manager database (by default Tridion_cm_email) in the fields definition of the table CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS whether the MAIL field is mandatory (Allows Nulls unchecked). 
You can use Sql Management studio to configure the CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS table.

Alternatively, do not include MAIL as part of the contact identification fields, since IDENTIFICATION_KEY is already usually the email address of the contact. For instance, check your tridion/config/OutboundEmail.xml file and look at the ContactDetails element.
Remove the isIdentificationKey="true" attribute from the MAIL element. e.g.:

```
<ContactDetail name="MAIL" enableSearch="true" isEmailAddress="true">
     <Label>E-mail address</Label>
  </ContactDetail>
```